# Vertical scroll bar for gridTable in MVC WebGrid

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, scrollbar, webgrid

I am using a `WebGrid` in my `mvc` application. Now I want to fix the height of the `WebGrid`. For this purpose, I need a `VerticalScrollBar` for the `gridTable` contents.

```
<div class="grid-div" id="webgridid">
                @grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "gridTable",
    headerStyle: "gridHead",
    footerStyle: "gridFooter",
    columns: new[]
    {
        grid.Column("name","Name", canSort: true, style: "name"),
        grid.Column("description","Description", canSort: true, style: "description"),
        grid.Column("duration","Duration", canSort: true, style: "duration"),
   })
</div>
```

This is my `div` which contains `WebGrid`. I need vertical scroll bar for only the `gridtable` part, not for `gridHead`(Header) and `gridFooter` (Footer).

I got a solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132847/add-a-vertical-scroll-to-a-webgrid-within-asp-net-mvc4-application). In that, they are setting the height for the `div` which contains the `webGrid` like,

```
<style type="text/css">
    .grid-div {
        width: 650px;
        height:250px;
        overflow-y:auto;
    }
</style>
```

But, here the scroll bar is common for the `gridTable` as well as its header and footer. So, If I scroll down the scroll bar, then the header and footer also moving along with scroll bar.

Then I tried to set height for `gridTable` like,

```
<style type="text/css">
    .gridTable {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 615px;
    max-height: 275px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    display: block;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: solid 1px #98BF21;
    background-color: white;
    text-wrap:inherit;
    }
</style>
```

But, Its not creating a vertical scroll bar even its height is greater than `275px`. What will be the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Setting a fixed `height` plus `overflow: scroll` or `overflow: auto` should work as expected. However, when you add `display: table` this will not work because tables ignore the height property, even `max-height` too, when combined with `overflow`.

Further reading: [Bugzilla Bug 26617 - table ignores height and overflow attributes](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26617)

The solution would be to remove the `display: table` property and make it a normal block / `display: block;`

```css
.grid-div > div {padding:1em;}

.grid-div .gridHead {background:#000; color:#FFF;}

.grid-div .gridFooter {background:lightblue;}

.grid-div .gridTable {
  background:#CCC;
  height:100px;
  display:block;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-div" id="webgridid">
  <div class="gridHead">.gridHead</div>
  <div class="gridTable">.gridTable <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero quasi assumenda atque, nemo molestias corrupti necessitatibus reiciendis voluptatem aliquid, id eos quam labore quos sunt quis temporibus, nisi architecto esse!</p></div>
  <div class="gridFooter">.gridFooter</div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k7y29mLx/

Comment: Here total 3 div is using to implement this. And not using WebGrid. But in my application I need a webGrid with Header, Footer and gridTable. So that I can bind the values directly to the grid table and it will display as different rows in gridTable.

Comment: I am not familiar with `WebGrid` but doesn't it eventually compile into `HTML` divs?

Comment: In my application, the gridTable of a WebGrid contains user details as rows and columns. So if I create header, footer and gridTable with 3 different div's then its difficult to bind datas from database to the gridTable

Comment: is the output an actual `table` tag? It shouldn't matter if it's a div or table or whatever. Just add the styles to the CSS class and make sure to have `display:block`